# Batch file extracting last token from unknown number of delimiters

Tags: batch-file, token, delimiter

I've tried the other answers that are similar to my question, but they are not working.  I set a variable "name" which is delimited by periods.  Some users have two tokens (e.g., "Bob.Smith") and some users have three (e.g., "Bob.J.Smith").  I just need to extract the last token from the "name" string and store it back into the "name" variable.  This is what I have:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set name=%USERNAME%
for /f "tokens=* delims=." %%A in ("%name%") do (
    set name=%%A
    echo !name!
    echo %%A
)
```

But it just returns the full initial "name" variable value.

I've also tried the following with no luck.

```
for /f "delims=." %%A in ("%name%") do set name=%%~nxA
```

Please help!

Comment: You would just use `%%~xA`.  If you read the help for the `FOR` command, the `n` is for the file name and `x` is for the extension.  But when you use `x` it also gives you the period.  So then you would need to use a substring to remove the first character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try like this:

```
set "name=Bob.J.Smith"
for %%a in ("%name:.=" "%") do set "last=%%~a"
echo %last%
```

Comment: Perhaps dump the Quotes? `set "last=%%~a"`

Comment: That was it!  Awesome, thank you!  Magoo's solution also worked great, but went with this one for ease of re-using variable in other parts of the batch file.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option that uses the `SET` command with the `&` to concatenate multiple string substitutions.

```
@echo off

set "name=Bob.J.Smith"
set "name=%name:.=" & set "name=%"
echo %name%
pause
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for %%A in ("%name%") do set name=%%~xA
echo %name:~1%
```

Interpreting `name` as a filename, select the extension part only and assign to `name`.

Then display `name` starting at "character 1" where the string starts at character 0.

Comment: aah. Clever.Though it will not work if the delimiter is not dot.